# Update only time in timestamp postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-timestamp

I have to update a timestamp in my database, but I want to change only the time, keeping the once registered date, for example, in '2021-10-07 11:00:00' I want to update it to '2021-10-07 10:00:00', how can I accomplish that?

the query I tried to run:

```
update p_bab.registro_ponto
set data_hora = timestamp::'10:00:00'
where id = 50;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
update p_bab.registro_ponto
set data_hora = data_hora - interval '1 hour'
where id = 50;
```

if not and you have a constant time to set then :

```
update p_bab.registro_ponto
set data_hora = date(data_hora) + interval '10 hour'
where id = 50;
```

or

```
update p_bab.registro_ponto
set data_hora = date(data_hora) + '10:30:23'::time
where id = 50;
```

Comment: So I can only opdate it with intervals? I can't set a specific hour?

Comment: @ThiagoSalgado see 3rd method

Comment: Oh, that's perfect, thanks a lot!